# How to fix a problem with dynamic date templates?

Tags: datetime, elasticsearch, bulk

I have a problem with dynamic date tampletes

I'm using ElasticSearch 6.2.4

My steps:

**1) Create index with next settings:**

```
PUT /test1
{
    "settings": {
        "index":{
            "number_of_shards" : 9,
            "number_of_replicas" : 0,
            "max_rescore_window" : 2000000000,
            "max_result_window" : 2000000000
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "files": {
            "properties": {
                "Дата добавления в БД": {
                    "type": "date"
                }
            },
            "numeric_detection": true,
            "dynamic_templates": [
                {
                    "integers": {
                        "match_mapping_type": "long",
                        "mapping": {
                            "type": "long"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "strings": {
                        "match_mapping_type": "string",
                        "mapping": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "dates": {
                        "match_mapping_type": "date",
                        "mapping": {
                            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss||yyyyMMdd_HH:mm:ss",
                            "type": "date"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**2) Try to put new records (I have only one)**

```
POST /test1/files/_bulk
{"create":{"_index":"test1","_type":"files","_id":"0"}}
{"Дата добавления в БД":"2019/04/12 11:42:21"}
```

**3) So, I have next output:**

```
{
    "took": 1,
    "errors": true,
    "items": [
        {
            "create": {
                "_index": "test1",
                "_type": "files",
                "_id": "0",
                "status": 400,
                "error": {
                    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
                    "reason": "failed to parse [Дата добавления в БД]",
                    "caused_by": {
                        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                        "reason": "Invalid format: \"2019/04/12 11:42:21\" is malformed at \"/04/12 11:42:21\""
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I can't understand where is my mistake?? 
I tried to find some information about this problem in Google, unfortunately, I have no solves of this problem. Maybe, this question is so stupid, but I've already broken my brain. 
Please, help me...

Answer (score 0):

I can't fully understand, but this option work:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "index":{
            "number_of_shards" : 9,
            "number_of_replicas" : 0,
            "max_rescore_window" : 2000000000,
            "max_result_window" : 2000000000
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "files": {
        "dynamic_date_formats": ["yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss","yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", "yyyyMMdd_HH:mm:ss"],
            "numeric_detection": true,
            "date_detection": true,

            "dynamic_templates": [
                {
                    "integers": {
                        "match_mapping_type": "long",
                        "mapping": {
                            "type": "long"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "strings": {
                        "match_mapping_type": "string",
                        "mapping": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Link to documentation:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/dynamic-field-mapping.html

Thanks for attention :)

Comment: FYI - the reason this works versus the original version is because you were originally *explicitly* defining a property of type date which takes precedence over your dynamic mappings.